# CMake Boost Libraries Not Found Windows7

Tags: boost, cmake, cgal, cmake-gui

I am getting the below error when trying to configure CGAL using cmake.
Does anyone have an insight on this error . The path is set accordingly but still the error keeps appearing

BOOST_ROOT = C:/dev/libboost_1_55_0/boost_1_55_0

BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = C:/dev/libboost_1_55_0/boost_1_55_0/boost

BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = C:/dev/libboost_1_55_0/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-12

Could not find the following static Boost libraries:

```
      boost_thread
      boost_system
```

Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
  need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
  BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
  to the location of Boost

Comment: Have you built those libraries? Those are two that are not header-only.

Comment: I Installed Pre-build binaries from source forge. I can see the lib in the dir                          boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55
boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_55

Comment: boost_1_55_0-msvc-12.0-32 , VS 2012 , Qt5.6.3

Comment: Solved this problem by installing Intel C++ compiler