# using cmake and boost. Unable to find the requested Boost libraries

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

I have been trying to install boost for a while now, and I simply cannot get it to work. I will go over everything I have done, so probably it will be easier to understand why it is not working.

I started to clone *Simple-WebSocket-Server* 
https://gitlab.com/eidheim/Simple-WebSocket-Server

I downloaded boost 1.67 
https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/

From the documentation 
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/more/getting_started/windows.html
I build everything using 
`bootstrap` 
`.\b2`

Output:

> The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built! 
>   The following directory should be added to compiler include paths: 
>      D:\boost_1_67_0 
>   The following directory should be added to linker library paths: 
>      D:\boost_1_67_0\stage\lib

When I try use cmake with the *Simple-WebSocket-Server*, I get the following output

> CMake Warning at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:577 (message): 
>     Imported targets and dependency information not available for Boost version
>     (all versions older than 1.33) 
>   Call Stack (most recent call first): 
>     C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:959 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES) 
>     C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1618 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES) 
>     src/extlibs/Simple-WebSocket-Server/CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)
>
> CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message): 
>     Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
>     directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
>     Boost's headers. 
>   Call Stack (most recent call first): 
>     src/extlibs/Simple-WebSocket-Server/CMakeLists.txt:35 (find_package)

After much searching, I have tried the following options 
[CMake finds Boost but the imported targets not available for Boost version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123509/cmake-finds-boost-but-the-imported-targets-not-available-for-boost-version) 
I already have the latest CMake (3.12.1)

[CMake with Boost library Windows 10 Library not found correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936353/cmake-with-boost-library-windows-10-library-not-found-correctly) 
I tried rebuilding with these options 
`bootstrap.bat` 
`b2 link=static runtime-link=static release stage` 
but still does not work

Following other answers, I added  
`set(BOOST_ROOT "D:/boost_1_67_0/")` 
and with, and without 
`set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "D:/boost_1_67_0/")` 
 
`set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "D:/boost_1_67_0/libs")` 
I have tried many variations of `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` and `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`, including to the msvc specific dir `lib64-msvc-14.1`

to the CMakeList.txt (Not prefered, as I want the project to be untouched)

changes the error to

> [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1883 ] Boost_FOUND = 1 
>   Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.
>
> Boost version: 1.67.0
>
> Boost include path: D:/boost_1_67_0
>
> Could not find the following Boost libraries:
>
> ```
>      boost_system
>      boost_thread
>      boost_coroutine
>      boost_context
> ```
>
> Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may
>     need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set
>     BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT
>     to the location of Boost.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     src/extlibs/Simple-WebSocket-Server/CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package)

I searched through the boost directory, and I have the 'missing' modules

I have even tried extract pre-built binaries, in case my build was faulty 
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.67.0/

The only thing that I have not tried yet is 
[CMake Boost Libraries Not Found Windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124671/cmake-boost-libraries-not-found-windows7#comment81462076_47124671)
but should not be necessary?

I have noticed that I have one difference from what 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33380087/9230431
says. I do not have a `include` directory inside the `boost_1_67_0` root directory.

cmake cache values

> BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF 
>   BUILD_TESTING:BOOL=OFF 
>   CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Debug;Release;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo 
>   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/PROJ 
>   GLFW_BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_DOCUMENT_INTERNALS:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_INSTALL:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG:BOOL=OFF 
>   GLFW_VULKAN_STATIC:BOOL=OFF 
>   LIB_EAY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=LIB_EAY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND 
>   LIB_EAY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=LIB_EAY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND 
>   LIB_SUFFIX:STRING=  
>   OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=D:/Strawberry/c/include  
>   Qt5Core_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5Core 
>   Qt5Gui_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui 
>   Qt5Network_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5Network 
>   Qt5OpenGL_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5OpenGL 
>   Qt5Widgets_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5Widgets 
>   Qt5_DIR:PATH=C:/Qt/5.10.1/msvc2015/lib/cmake/Qt5 
>   SSL_EAY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=SSL_EAY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND 
>   SSL_EAY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=SSL_EAY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND 
>   USE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY_DLL:BOOL=ON 
>   USE_STANDALONE_ASIO:BOOL=OFF

Full cmake output

> Using Win32 for window creation 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1121 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1123 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = TRUE 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1125 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1127 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1129 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1131 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1199 ] Declared as CMake or Environmental Variables: 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1201 ]   BOOST_ROOT = D:/boost_1_67_0/ 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1203 ]   BOOST_INCLUDEDIR =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1205 ]   BOOST_LIBRARYDIR =  
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1207 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = 1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1282 ] Include debugging info: 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1284 ]   _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = D:/boost_1_67_0//include;D:/boost_1_67_0/;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_68_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_68;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_67_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_67;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_66_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_66;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_64_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_64;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_63_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_63;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_62_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_62;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_61_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_61;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_60_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_60;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_59_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_59;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_58_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_58;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_57_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_57;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_56_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_56;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_55_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_55;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_54_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_54;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_53_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_53;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_52_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_52;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_51_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_51;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_50_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_50;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_49_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_49;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_48_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_48;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_47_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_47;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_45_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_45;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_44_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_44;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_43_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_43;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_42_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_42;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_41_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_41;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_40_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_40;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_39_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_39;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_38_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_38;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_37_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_37;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1286 ]   _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = boost-1_68_0;boost_1_68_0;boost/boost-1_68_0;boost/boost_1_68_0;boost-1_68;boost_1_68;boost/boost-1_68;boost/boost_1_68;boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1306 ] location of version.hpp: D:/boost_1_67_0/boost/version.hpp 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1330 ] version.hpp reveals boost 1.67.0 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1416 ] guessed _boost_COMPILER = -vc141;-vc140 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1426 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = -mt 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1502 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = - 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1504 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = -gd 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1567 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = D:/boost_1_67_0//lib;D:/boost_1_67_0//stage/lib;D:/boost_1_67_0//lib32-msvc-14.1;D:/boost_1_67_0//lib32-msvc-14.0;D:/boost_1_67_0/lib;D:/boost_1_67_0/../lib;D:/boost_1_67_0/stage/lib;D:/boost_1_67_0/../lib32-msvc-14.1;D:/boost_1_67_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;D:/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;D:/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.1;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.0; THIS LINE IS HEAVILY REDUCED DUE TO CHARACTER LIMIT! 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_system-vc141-mt;boost_system-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_system-vc140-mt;boost_system-mt-x32-1_67;boost_system-mt;boost_system 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_system-vc141-mt-gd;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_thread-vc141-mt;boost_thread-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_thread-vc140-mt;boost_thread-mt-x32-1_67;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd;boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_thread-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for COROUTINE_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_coroutine-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-vc141-mt;boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-vc140-mt;boost_coroutine-mt-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-mt;boost_coroutine 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for COROUTINE_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_coroutine-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-vc141-mt-gd;boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-vc140-mt-gd;boost_coroutine-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_coroutine-mt-gd;boost_coroutine-mt;boost_coroutine 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for CONTEXT_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_context-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_context-vc141-mt;boost_context-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_context-vc140-mt;boost_context-mt-x32-1_67;boost_context-mt;boost_context 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for CONTEXT_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_context-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_context-vc141-mt-gd;boost_context-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_context-vc140-mt-gd;boost_context-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_context-mt-gd;boost_context-mt;boost_context 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-vc141-mt;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-vc140-mt;boost_chrono-mt-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-vc141-mt-gd;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_chrono-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-vc141-mt;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-vc140-mt;boost_date_time-mt-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-vc141-mt-gd;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_date_time-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1756 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-vc141-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc141-mt;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc140-mt;boost_atomic-mt-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1809 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc141-mt-gd;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd;boost_atomic-mt-gd-x32-1_67;boost_atomic-mt-gd;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic 
>   [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1883 ] Boost_FOUND = 1 
>   CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.12/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2044 (message): 
>     Unable to find the requested Boost libraries. 
>    
>     Boost version: 1.67.0 
>    
>     Boost include path: D:/boost_1_67_0 
>    
>     Could not find the following Boost libraries: 
>    
>             boost_system 
>             boost_thread 
>             boost_coroutine 
>             boost_context 
>    
>     Some (but not all) of the required Boost libraries were found.  You may 
>     need to install these additional Boost libraries.  Alternatively, set 
>     BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT 
>     to the location of Boost. 
>   Call Stack (most recent call first): 
>     src/extlibs/Simple-WebSocket-Server/CMakeLists.txt:36 (find_package) 
>    
>    
>   CMake Warning (dev) at src/extlibs/Simple-WebSocket-Server/CMakeLists.txt:39 (if): 
>     Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or 
>     keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy 
>     details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this 
>     warning. 
>    
>     Quoted variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy 
>     is set to NEW.  Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used. 
>   This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it. 
>    
>    
>    
>   Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! 
>   See also "C:/Users/Klient/Desktop/WFM Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". 
>   See also "C:/Users/Klient/Desktop/WFM Build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Comment: I would start from the prebuilt libraries from 

https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.67.0/boost_1_67_0-msvc-14.1-64.exe or the according 32-Bit version

and make that work. And you may need to skip the version number 1.54.0 in the `find_package(Boost ...)` calls in CMakeLists.txt.

For further settings see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954471/cmake-found-and-not-found-boost-simultaneously/51975821#51975821

Sometimes you may need to delete the CMakeCache.txt file when doing changes to the CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: I just reinstalled everything, and rebuilt everything again. Everything works now. I do not know exactly what was the problem, but I think it may be related to the CMakeCache. I noticed that using cmake-gui and cmake from the command prompt use different cache, so I may not have deleted all of the cache during retries.

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. I do not know exactly what it was, I simply reinstalled everything and built everything again. I think it may be related to the CMakeCache, as vre suggested, due to the cmake-gui and command prompt use different cache.